# What is meaning of morphs' realizing lexemes?

Tags: terminology

Hollo, I think realizing in linguistics generally means that some units abstractly defined get instantiated by more concrete forms. But I encounters a usage of "realise" in a linguistic book, which I have difficulty to understand.

More specifically, that book fist list an English sentence:

> (12) Everyone lives by selling something.

Then it goes on to give the following account:

> In (12), it so happens that all of the potentially free morphs realise lexemes and none of the obligatorily bound morphs do. This is typically the case in English but not invariably the case. In other languages, such as Latin, for example, it is typically the case that the morphs realising lexemes are also obligatorily bound.

It seems none of the explanation of the word "realise" used here that I can think of can make the above passage meaningful. Could anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: _Lexeme_ is a very abstract term, and they seem to be using "realize" to indicate actual use in speech of something with a lexeme at its base (the metaphor is deep/surface structure, most likely). What they mean to say is that in English, most lexical morphemes can occur without affixation, whereas in Latin almost every word is inflected or modified in some way from its "base" lexeme. That's a root/stem/plant metaphor, where the word grows like a plant.

Comment: @jlawler but then in (12) "selling" and "lives" are also inflected and bot base in any sense I suppose? Why they say that none of the obligatorily bound morphs in (12) realise lexemes while claime most morphs realising lexemes in Latin are also obligatorily boubd? I'm really confused…

Comment: Well, for instance, the Latin root _amic-_ 'friend' never occurs without an ending; the nominatives _amicus_ and _amica_ do occur, but they're inflected for gender, number (singular) and case (nominative). Whereas the English verb root _sell_ does exist -- it's the infinitive and the present tense form, and it is uninflected, except by zero affixes, if you want to believe in them.

Comment: @jlawler thanks, now I tjink I get the point… What this passage means is this: in(12), the morph "every" realises the lexeme "EVERY", the morph "tell" realises the lexeme "TELL", etc. while the morph "ing" doesn't realise any lexeme. In Latin a morph like "amic" also realise a lexeme which can be named "FRIEND",  but in real passages, this lexeme can only be realised as word forms like "amicus" or "amica", but not merely "amic"*…